# Evaluate the sum using derivatives and generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\frac{(k+3)!}{(k-1)!}$.

My strategy is defining a generating function,
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2...$$
then shifting it so that we get,
$$f(x)=x^4g(x) = \frac{x^4}{1-x}= x^4+x^5+...$$
and then taking the 4th derivative of f(x).
Calculating the fourth derivative is going to be a little tedious but it won't be as bad compared to the partial fraction decomposition I will end up doing. What is a better way to evaluate the sum using generating functions?

Comment: The summand is $(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)k=k^4 + 6 k^3 + 11 k^2 + 6 k$.  I don't see where $\frac 1{1-x}$ comes into it.

Comment: @lulu Well, if you take 4th derivatives of LHS, it's actually the sum asked. (After putting $x=1$)

Comment: @rachel I think this is actually a good strategy. Recognizing $(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)k$ as coming from $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}x^{k+3}$ is a nice idea.

Comment: @zwim is it really a good idea considering that doing partial fraction decomposition will be incredibly tedious? unless you're seeing something I am not?

Comment: Hum, yes, even if all coefficients are indeed $0$ except for $(1-x)^0$ this coefficient is tedious to come with. There is another method (shown in answer) but it doesn't use generating functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you differentiate $g(x)$ $4$ times all powers of $x$ initially less than $4$ disappear anyway.

Then:

$$g^{(4)}(x)=4!(1-x)^{-5}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(k+4)!}{k!}x^k$$

Operating with $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ on both sides gives a new expansion with terms which are partial sums of the coefficients of $x^k$ in the previous expansion:

$$(1-x)^{-1}g^{(4)}(x)=\sum_{r\ge 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{r}\frac{(k+4)!}{k!}\right)x^r$$

so

$$4!(1-x)^{-6}=\sum_{r\ge 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{r}\frac{(k+4)!}{k!}\right)x^r$$

$$\implies [x^r]4!(1-x)^{-6}=4!\binom{r+5}{5}=\sum_{k=0}^{r}\frac{(k+4)!}{k!}$$

but $r=n-4$ to match up with $n$ in the question, so

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}\frac{(k+4)!}{k!}=4!\binom{n+1}{5}\tag{Answer}$$

This summation is the same as the one in the question with only a shift in summation index.

Of course you may notice that this is just [Pascal's hockey stick rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: Nice! the only thing I don't follow is how $[x^r]4!(1-x)^{-6} = 4!{r+5 \choose 5} = \sum_{k=0}^{r}\frac{k+4}{k!}$? and did you mean (k+4)! in $\frac{k+4}{k!}$? also, what is $[x^r]?$ I'm sorry, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @rachelhoward. Yes, sorry, it's $(k+4)!/k!$, I'll edit that. $[x^r]$ is an operator which means "take the $x^r$ coefficient of". So, for example $$[x^r](1-x)^{-(t+1)}=\binom{r+t}{t}$$ since $$(1-x)^{-(t+1)}=\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{r+t}{t}x^r\, .$$

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $U_4(k)= k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$

Then $U_4(k)-U_4(k-1)=k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)\bigg((k+4)-(k-1)\bigg)=5U_3(k)$

Thus you get a telescoping series and

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-3}k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)=\dfrac 15\bigg(U_4(n-3)-U_4(0)\bigg)=\dfrac 15U_4(n-3)\\=\dfrac{(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)(n)(n+1)}5$$

Comment: What is the subscript 4 of U? and where are you getting the 1 over 5 and where/how are you getting the last expression?

Comment: $U_p(k)=k(k+1)\cdots(k+p)$ and you sum $U_3(k)$ all the rest is substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation using generating functions *without* differentiation. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for $n\geq 4$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\frac{(k+3)!}{(k-1)!}}
> &=4!\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\binom{k+3}{4}=4!\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}\binom{k+4}{4}\tag{2}\\
> &=4!\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}[x^4](1+x)^{k+4}\tag{3}\\
> &=4![x^4](1+x)^4\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}(1+x)^k\tag{4}\\
> &=4![x^4](1+x)^4\frac{(1+x)^{n-3}-1}{(1+x)-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=4![x^5](1+x)^{n+1}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4!\binom{n+1}{5}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we write the fraction using binomial coefficients and shift the index by one to start with $k=0$.
- In (3) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (5) we apply the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* formula.
- In (6) we do some simplifications, apply the rule $[x^{p+q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^{-q}A(x)$ and ignore $(1+x)^{4}$ since it does not contribute to $[x^5]$.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $[x^5]$ accordingly.

Comment: (+1) Your answers are always so wonderfully well structured. I am still playing with geogebra btw. It sometimes crashes though. I wonder if it is just the version for android.

Comment: @N.Shales: Many thanks for your nice comment and also (+1) to your answer which is nicely presented and fits perfectly OPs needs.

Comment: You're most welcome. Thanks! Hope to see you around.